# Server.MapPath() wrong path on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to upload image to a folder called 
`~/Avatars/`.

My project is located in VS2010 projects folder 
`C:/Projects/MyProject.

When i try to get **physical path** to Avatars folder by

```
Server.MapPath("/Avatars")
```

it always returns

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Avatars
```

instead of

```
C:\Projects\MyProject\Avatars.
```

It works fine when I run the project on VS2010 **dev** server.

Can anyone help me how to get **actual path** in IIS?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're deploying to IIS and that's the default folder for deployment. When you run locally, dev server runs off your local folder.

What you need is `Server.MapPath("~/Avatars")` or `Server.MapPath("Avatars")`. Also, make sure when you deploy to IIS, you're site is being deployed to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\My Project\`.

Comment: How do I deploy to My Project folder in IIS root? I tried to change the output folder to this directory but its only deploying dlls, not project files

Comment: Use Visual Studio's publish feature. You only need dlls, aspx/ascx and config files (JS and images too if you have them).

Answer (score 2):

Check whether virtual directory named  **Avatars**  is not created in IIS that points to the path: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Avatars".

In that case Server.Mappath returns the same path. In such case remove that Virtual Directory from IIS

Answer (score 1):

It seems that virtual directory for your project was created inside of the "Default Web Site". So, if your virtual directory called "myapp", to access your site, you should type in the address bar "http://localhost/myapp". Therefore, "/" will point to "http://localhost" and its physical path will be "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".

When you run on VS Developer Server (IIS Express), you access your site via URL like "http://localhost:42111/". So, "/" will point to "http://localhost:42111/" and its physical path will be "C:\Projects\MyProject".

For me, the easiest way to fix this problem would be re-creating virtual folder for your site. Delete the existing virtual folder and create new one outside of the "Default Web Site". You will have to assign another TCP port (not 80) for your site. If you will do so, you will access your site via URL like "http://localhost:8080/". Or, you can configure "Default Web Site" to run on another port and assign port 80 for your site. Either way,  "/" will point to "http://localhost:your_port/" with physical path "C:\Projects\MyProject". In that case Server.MapPath will work fine for you.